# docker-compose container port not showing up on localhost

Tags: python, docker, docker-container

I am trying to run a docker-compose app that has two services. One to build a web server and the other to run the tests on it.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:5000:5000"
    expose:
      - 5000
  test:
    # expose:
    #   - 5000
    depends_on: 
      - web
    build: test_python/.
```

`./Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:buster
RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y

# Add .cargo/bin to PATH
ENV PATH="/root/.cargo/bin:${PATH}"

# Check cargo is visible
RUN cargo --help
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r  requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
COPY test_python .
CMD [ "python3", "base_routes.py" ]
```

`test_python/Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:buster
RUN pip3 install pytest requests
COPY . .
```

`base_routes.py`

```
from robyn import Robyn, static_file, jsonify
import asyncio

app = Robyn(__file__)

callCount = 0


@app.get("/")
async def h(request):
    print(request)
    global callCount
    callCount += 1
    message = "Called " + str(callCount) + " times"
    return message

@app.get("/test")
async def test(request):
    import os
    path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "test_python/index.html"))
    return static_file(path)

@app.get("/jsonify")
async def json_get(request):
    return jsonify({"hello": "world"})


@app.post("/jsonify")
async def json(request):
    print(request)
    return jsonify({"hello": "world"})

@app.post("/post")
async def postreq(request):
    return bytearray(request["body"]).decode("utf-8")

@app.put("/put")
async def putreq(request):
    return bytearray(request["body"]).decode("utf-8")

@app.delete("/delete")
async def deletereq(request):
    return bytearray(request["body"]).decode("utf-8")

@app.patch("/patch")
async def patchreq(request):
    return bytearray(request["body"]).decode("utf-8")

@app.get("/sleep")
async def sleeper():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    return "sleep function"


@app.get("/blocker")
def blocker():
    import time
    time.sleep(10)
    return "blocker function"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.add_header("server", "robyn")
    app.add_directory(route="/test_dir",directory_path="./test_dir/build", index_file="index.html")
    app.start(port=5000)
```

These are the files that I have used in my project. When I try to open `127.0.0.1:5000` from my machine, it shows nothing. However, when I log in the `web` container and do `curl http://localhost:5000/`, it gives the right response.

I am unable to figure out how to access it on the host machine?

Comment: Whats does `docker container ls` show concerning these containers?

Comment: @RobBlanchard, it shows this 

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE       COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
aa7a591d9ea9   robyn_web   "python3 base_routes…"   43 minutes ago   Up About a minute   127.0.0.1:5000->5000/tcp   robyn_web_1
```

Comment: Is the base_route.py a flask application? I guess you have binded the web application and the docker container both of them to the same address - localhost.

Comment: Make sure your app listens to 0.0.0.0!

Comment: @RuhanSharief , no it is not a Flask app. It is a Robyn app, a framework created by me. The API is similar to Flask but they are two different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make the python server listen at '0.0.0.0'.

I added the following line in my codebase

```
    app.start(port=5000, url='0.0.0.0')
```